# Installing Unirest-Java to consume a Mashape API

Tags: maven, mashape, unirest

I created this simple class:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpResponse;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.JsonNode;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.Unirest;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.exceptions.UnirestException;

public class TweetSent {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            HttpResponse<JsonNode> request = Unirest.get("https://intridea-tweetsentiments.p.mashape.com/twitsentiment/?num_tweets=10&query=%3Cquery%3E").basicAuth("X-Mashape-Authorization", "#######################").asJson();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"request: "+request);
        } catch (UnirestException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"ERROR: "+e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

But I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64
    at com.mashape.unirest.request.HttpRequest.basicAuth(HttpRequest.java:61)
    at com.NR.V.TweetSent.main(TweetSent.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
```

**EDIT:**

I removed all of the `<repository>` elements mentioned in the `pom.xml` file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mashape.unirest</groupId>
    <artifactId>unirest-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpasyncclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.0-beta4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
    <version>4.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20090211</version>
</dependency>
```

I get this from Maven:

```
[WARNING] The POM for com.mashape.unirest:unirest-java:jar:1.3.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm the author of [Unirest-Java](https://github.com/mashape/unirest-java).

Can you please update Unirest to its latest version? This problem should have been fixed with version `1.3.0`.

Also make sure to have imported all the required dependencies. You can read the installation instructions at https://github.com/Mashape/unirest-java#installing

**Edit:** To force Maven to re-download the library, try deleting the `unirest-java` folder at `~/.m2/repository/com/mashape/unirest/unirest-java/` and execute `mvn clean compile` again.

Comment: Maven says it can't find artifact 1.3.0-SNAPSHOT, but it can find 1.2.8

Comment: Unirest now uses Maven Central. Try to remove the <repositories> entry. As you can see, it has been properly uploaded: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/mashape/unirest/unirest-java/1.3.0-SNAPSHOT/

Comment: Still no luck. Please see EDIT 2 in question.

Comment: This works for me: delete the "unirest-java" folder at "~/.m2/repository/com/mashape/unirest/unirest-java/" and execute "mvn clean compile" again. It should re-download the library from Maven Central. Answer updated.

Comment: And please update the version from `1.3.0-SNAPSHOT` to `1.3.0`

Comment: Please look at picture of folder structure above. I deleted mashape as you suggested, but when it was regenerated "SNAPSHOT" version appears. But still I get Maven cannot find it!

Comment: This is very weird, the SNAPSHOT shouldn't be downloaded if the version is set to "1.3.0". The following pom.xml file works for me: https://gist.github.com/thefosk/7325187 I've also tried it on fresh installations, and it works. Try to download it and execute "mvn clean compile" to see if it works (delete the Unirest folder again in your local repository).

Answer (score 0):

It's advisable to package everything in one uber jar by using Maven.

Please refer to this [post](http://blog.mashape.com/post/69117323931/installing-unirest-java-with-the-maven-assembly-plugin) on how to use Unirest in your Java projects.